# Convert SQL to activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

What is the most efficient activerecord statment for the following sql query?

```
update apples
set 
revokable = true
where
fruit_id = 2 and id != 41;
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Apples.update_all("revokable=true", ["fruit_id=? and id not in ?"], 2, 41)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged as Rails 4.  In Rails 4, `update_all` changed from  the format:

[update_all(updates, conditions = nil, options = {})](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb)

to:

[update_all(updates)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb)

So you'll want to use something like:

```
Apple.where(fruit_id: 2).where.not(id: 41).update_all(revokable: true)
```

This removes the need to write raw SQL in a string and it allows you to more easily reuse conditions elsewhere.  For example, you could start to define scopes to document what the conditions mean:

```
# Apple model
scope :not_red_delicious, -> { where.not(id: 41) }

# New ActiveRecord query
Apple.where(fruit_id: 2).not_red_delicious.update_all(revokable: true)
```

Comment: +1 always good to get away from writing raw SQL. Also good use of scopes to make things even more readable.